# telerik MVC extension loses formatting after refreshing partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I'm using the following line within a partial view (ASP.NET MVC4):

```
@Html.Telerik().CurrencyTextBoxFor(x => x.LineItems[ndx].Amount).Spinners(false)
```

The values initially display with correct formatting; for example:  $1,234.56.  But after refreshing the partial view all formatting is lost.  The previous example may display as 1234.56000.

The Telerik code base is 2012 Q2.

How can I trigger a refresh in this situation?

Comment: Same problem here with the Telerik grid.

Comment: Did you solve the issue ? I have same problem.

Comment: @umki unfortunately no.  I abandon CurrencyTextBox and wrote my own  JavaScript to format as currency

Comment: If i included the whole telerik related scripts into partial view, problem solved but it is not effective...

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere I found this answer. It is obscure and non-intuitive. But it definitely worked for me. MVC 5, .NET 6.0. This makes sense because the partial view doesn't have all the formatting.

```
 return View("_LoadAgentSetting", agentsettings); //works
 //return PartialView("_LoadAgentSetting"); // loses formatting
```